# Чекер FPS для мобильных платформ

Tags: android, ios, app

Есть желание собрать приложение(для ios и android), которое будет чекать ФПС у заданных приложений на устройстве. Подскажите, на какие процессы/команды нужно обратить внимание для этого. Буду очень благодарен